# How to compile a new version of a Firefox extension?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I have the source code with the changes I made, and I need to get an `.xpi` file. I understand we are not necessarily using a *compiler*, but somehow I need to *build* this `.xpi` file.

My users are downloading a single `.xpi` file and loading it into Firefox to use. So I need to update the version number, build a `.xpi` file and sign it, if needed.

I was not the original developer, but my changes involve basic Javascript changes.

Answer (score 2):

An `.xpi` file is basically a `.zip` file with the file extension name changed.

I just use a regular zipping program, *7-Zip* or *MS Windows* (7, 8, 8.1) Context Menu `"Send To... > Compressed (zipped) folder"`).

Then, make sure File Extensions are shown, and rename `foo.zip` to `foo.xpi`.

You can then give it to users to install.

---

**To answer your comment:**

Yes, you need to get it signed by [AMO](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/) (**a**ddons.**m**ozilla.**o**rg).

It is still possible to install unsigned add-ons up until Firefox 46, by changing a preference in `about:config`, but after 46 is released, it will not be possible.

You can sign it by first creating a Firefox Account (AMO just stated using Firefox Accounts instead of their own separate account) and logging in on AMO (hopefully you can work out how to do this!).

Then in the nav-bar, click `Tools > Submit a New Add-on...`. You will need to Upload your `.xpi` file (note that you can upload `.zip` and `.jar` files). Then upload an image, write a description, etc.

At some point (normally when you upload the file), it will ask if you want your add-on to be *Listed*, *Hidden* or *Unlisted*:

- A *Listed* add-on lets people download it on AMO as well as your own site / own method of distribution. Anyone on AMO can see your add-on
- A *Hidden* add-on is hosted by AMO, but not visible to anyone but the authors (in this case, you)
- An *Unlisted* add-on is not hosted on AMO. You have to distribute the file yourself.

Actually, here is a quote of the text exactly as it is on AMO:

> **Addon Visibility**
>
> **Listed:** Visible to everyone on https://addons.mozilla.org and included in search results and listing pages
>
> **Hidden:** Hosted on https://addons.mozilla.org, but hidden to anyone but authors. Used to temporarily hide listings or discontinue them.
>
> **Unlisted:** Not distributed on https://addons.mozilla.org. Developers will upload new versions for signing and distribute the
>   add-ons on their own. (beta)

Note that *Unlisted* is currently in **Beta**

Read [this section](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Distribution) on MDN for more information

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So do I need to sign it or anything else?

Comment: No problem. Yes, you will need it signed, read my edited answer. If this answered your question, please mark it as accepted.